# Flutter Geolocator showing the method toDouble() was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, geolocation

I am having an issue with Geolocator plugin in flutter.The error shows toDouble() was called on null. The app fetches latitude and longitude from Firebase and calculates the distance relative from user distance. The data loads and calculates the distance correctly but only after a red screen shows in the mobile device. [Image of error log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAUrA.png)

Here is my code below

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:e_commerce/Screen/HomeContent/HomeList/getdata.dart';
import 'package:e_commerce/Screen/HomeContent/HomeList/locationProvider.dart';
import 'package:e_commerce/Services/TestDirection/getCurrentLocation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:sortedmap/sortedmap.dart';

class TestUI extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestUI({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestUIState createState() => _TestUIState();
}

class _TestUIState extends State<TestUI> {
  BusinessServices _businessServices = BusinessServices();
  var _userLatitude;
  var _userLongitude;

  _getCurrentLocation() async {
    var locate = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    setState(() {
      _userLatitude = locate.latitude;
      _userLongitude = locate.longitude;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
  }

  String getDistance(location) {
    var distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
        _userLatitude, _userLongitude, location.latitude, location.longitude);

    var distanceInKm = distance / 1000;
    return distanceInKm.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _businessServices.getBusiness(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapShot) {
          if (!snapShot.hasData)
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          else {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    children:
                        snapShot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      if (double.parse(getDistance(document['location'])) <=
                          10) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10,
                              right: 10,
                              top: 5,
                              bottom: 5,
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                        imageUrl: document['image'],
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      )),
                                  ListTile(
                                      subtitle: ListView(
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          physics:
                                              NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                          children: [
                                            RatingBarIndicator(
                                              rating:
                                                  document["rating"].toDouble(),
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                                  const Icon(
                                                Icons.star,
                                                color: Colors.amber,
                                              ),
                                              itemCount: 5,
                                              itemSize: 18.0,
                                              direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                            ),
                                          ]),
                                      title: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(document['name']),
                                          Text(
                                              "${getDistance(document['location'])} km",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey[700])),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lots of things are looking wrong here, avoid using dynamic types, your location parameter should be of type Position but it isn't, do you know what type of data is stored in your firestore for location... My guess is it's GeoPoint so are you getting a proper geopoint? And I think the main issue is rating.. Check that thoroughly.

Comment: Actually rating is not the problem it worked before but now when i added the geolocator this exception came i think u figured what caused the error it's because of _userlatitude and _userlongitude have null at first but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: @IhsanAhmed do one thing, just give them a default value or just show some loading indicator until the value is loaded. Or else, use it like _userlatitude??somedefaultlat... Or loading indicator like if(userlatitude==null)  return loadingwidget(); else return contentWidget();